# Making a method only available to my tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rest

I'm trying to create a REST API library. I'm looking to find a way to expose just one method, in this case a method serving to delete objects I've used to test, to only my unit tests.

Basically this is just to clean up after each test. It also makes no sense to expose this delete method to any of my clients and is actually dangerous (deletes should be manual).

I found

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("FunctionalTests")]
```

But it doesn't seem to affect the visibility of the method. Any ideas? I couldn't find any other questions addressing this specific issue.

Thanks!

Edit 1: 
The method in question is already marked internal. The class is public and has a public interface that does not contain the method in question.

```
public class Access: IAccess, IDisposable
```

Which contains the method:

```
 internal void DeleteIssue(string issueKey)
```

Yet it cannot be accessed by calling

```
AccessInstance.DeleteIssue(TestIssueKey);
```

It returns an error "Access does not contain a definition for 'DeleteIssue' accepting a first argument of type 'Access' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" I am in the same Namespace.

Comment: Test projects are usually named with a dot.. so if your mvc is named MySite, VS typically creates MySite.Test - u sure you pass correct name for your UT assembly?

Comment: Resharper tells me "'assembly' is not a valid attribute location for this declaration. All attributes in this block will be ignored". I have tried changing the string for the InteralsVisibleTo without that changing or the error changing.

Comment: where did you put your `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("FunctionalTests")] ` code?  Is it in AssemblyInfo.cs ?

Comment: Erg. That was exactly the problem. I put it above my class name. 
It works now... it's in AssemblyInfo.cs. Now the question is, how do I flag the "right answer"?

Comment: Gr8t!, I reposted my comment as answer so you can mark it as answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("FunctionalTests")]` should be declared in AssemblyInfo.cs for it to work.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah that's exactly what it was. So used to those kinds of statements going above methods it never dawned on me.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your methods you want to use are declared internal - private methods won't be exposed outside of the assembly even with InternalsVisibleTo:

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Ordinarily, types and members with internal scope (in C#) and friend
>   scope (in Visual Basic) are visible only in the assembly in which they
>   are defined. The InternalsVisibleToAttribute attribute makes them also
>   visible to the types in a specified assembly, which is known as a
>   friend assembly.